# Getting Twitter's username and friend list using php

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

There is any way I can get the screen name and the list of Twitter friends, using Php, receiving only consumerKey and consumerSecret?

I am responsible for making the web server to which mobile devices will connect. The idea is to make the register in the system with Twitter, so it can be done faster.

Mobile devices using Fabric and they pass me the consumer key and the consumer  Secret.

I get the connection using:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth ($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

but when I try to

```
$friends = $connection-> get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json");
```

this is the response from server ( debug($friends); )

```
object(stdClass) {
    errors => array(
        (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
            code => (int) 89
            message => 'Invalid or expired token.'
        }
    )
}
```

Any help? Thx!